# How to Show NStimer's countdown at UILabel for 9 min 59 sec with Minitue and Second format?

Tags: nstimer

I have a task to add a timer on my apps which is appear on exam mode page. I have done every thing but can't convert total time into min:sec format. Please Anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: - (void) timerUpdate{

int miniute, Second;

timerValue--;

minutes = timerValue / 60;
seconds = (timerValue %60) % 60;

timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo arithmetic:

```
int totalSecondsRemaining = // however you obtain it
int minutesRemaining = totalSecondsRemaining / 60; // integer division, truncates fractional part
int secondsRemaining = totalSecondsRemaining % 60; // modulo division

someLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutesRemaining, secondsRemaining];
```

(Remark: this is elementary school maths...)